# TFS2010 - Teambuild detailed logfile

Tags: logging, build-process

With msbuild you can configure multiple loggers using different logging levels, e.g. errors are logged to console and all detailed information gets logged to a file.

Is there a similar option to configure the teambuild of TFS2010 to have "Normal" logs within my build summary "View Log" and to have a "Detailed" log within the output folder?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add additional command line arguments for MSBuild. On the build definition's Process->Advanced settings page change "MSBuild arguments" value. Try to use

```
/fileLogger /flp:LogFile=c:\DiagnosticBuild.log;Verbosity=diagnostic
```

Change your build log file name and location after successful test. If you need to log per MsBuild node, try to use distributedFileLogger instead of fileLogger.

Comment: It is not only for the msbuild output. In fact I search for a solution of the teambuild logs.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not available for the 2010 release, but a similar feature has been added for the next release. You just need to wait a bit :-)